# Python:not getting Length of longest common subsequence of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I tried to implement in LCS in simplest way I can but I am not getting the right value. Instead of 4 I get . I am not sure whats wrong with my code:

```
X= ['A','B','C','B','D','A','B']
Y= ['B','D','C','A','B','A','X','Y']

m= len(X)
n= len(Y)
c={}
for i in range(1,m) :
    c[i,0]=0

for j in range(0,n):
    c[0,j]=0

for i in range (1,m):
    for j in range (1,n):
        if X[i]==Y[j]:
            c[i,j]=c[i-1,j-1]+1
        elif c[i-1,j] >= c[i,j-1]:
            c[i,j]=c[i-1,j]
        else:
            c[i,j]=c[i,j-1]


print c[m-1,n-1]
print c
```

Comment: c[i,0]=0 - This line looks like bad syntax - what do you think this line is doing? Also.. what result are you getting, and what result do you want to get? Give examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the one-indexing you're using might be the root of your problem. If I understand correctly, you're looking for the LCS 'BCBA' of length 4, but you never actually compare the first entry to anything, so you don't have the opportunity to match the 'B' that is the first element of Y.

I made some slight modifications to your code and got a solution of 4:

```
X = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'B']
Y = ['B', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'X', 'Y']

m = len(X)
n = len(Y)
c = {}
for i in range(0, m+1):
    c[i, 0] = 0

for j in range(0, n+1):
    c[0, j] = 0

for i in range(1, m + 1):
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        if X[i-1] == Y[j-1]:
            c[i, j] = c[i - 1, j - 1] + 1
        else:
            c[i, j] = max(c[i-1, j],
                          c[i, j-1])
print c[m, n]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation I used for LCS, it returns `(percent_in_common, sequence_in_common)`

```
def longest_common_sequence(a,b):
   from collections import deque

   n1=len(a)
   n2=len(b)
   if not n1:
      if not n2:
         return 100.0, ''
      return 0.0, ''
   if not n2:
      return 0.0, ''
   previous=deque()
   for i in range(n2):
      previous.append((0,''))
   over = (0,'')
   for i in range(n1):
      left = corner = (0,'')
      for j in range(n2):
         over = previous.popleft()
         if a[i] == b[j]:
            this = corner[0] + 1, corner[1]+a[i]
         else:
            this = max(over,left)
         previous.append(this)
         left, corner = this, over
   return round(200.0*this[0]/(n1+n2),2),this[1]
```